# How can I always run a local task once with ansible regardless what limit parameter enforces?

Tags: ansible

I need to run once a local command before continuing normal playbook execution but this breaks once someone calls `ansible-playbook -l foo playbook.yml`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve that by combining few tricks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- hosts: all  # <--
  connection: local  # <--
  gather_facts: false  # <--
  strategy: linear  # <--
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "indeed!"
      run_once: true   # <--
```

All 5 are needed in order to achieve the desired effect of running once regadless if --limit is used or not.

Comment: you can add tags: always to the task if you want it to run when tags are specified